# Does cannibalism count as food?

Tags: achievements, fallout-new-vegas

I'm going for the Desert Survivalist achievement, and throughout my Fallout experiences, I've never taken the Cannibalism perk. I'm thinking that, since I'm playing a very evil character this time, I might take Cannibalism at some point. If I do, does engaging in cannibalism count as food?

And what of the Ghastly Scavenger perk? Does feasting on ghouls and super mutants count as food?

(Wow, this sounds sick as I read it ... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if consuming corpses directly counts. Even if it doesn't, once you've consumed 25, you'll gain the [Dine and Dash](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dine_and_Dash) challenge perk, which allows you to harvest [Human Remains](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Human_remains), which can be used from your inventory, and are most definitely food.

Ghastly Scavenger is unaffected by Dine and Dash, so if eating corpses directly doesn't count, then I suspect the same would apply for super mutants et al. The easiest way to test this by the way, is to take the perk, and check the challenge counter viewable on your Pip-Boy before eating a corpse.

Comment: Consuming corpses doesn't count; I've used the technique of checking the challenge counter on the PIP-Boy as you recommended.