# Is there a peaceful solution to Primm?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

This may sound odd coming from the psychopath who [slaughtered everyone in Fallout 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6518/ramifications-of-mass-slaughter) and was concerned about whether or not [cannibalism counted as food](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11556/does-cannibalism-count-as-food) (not to mention what would happen if I engaged in it [openly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11671/what-are-the-ramifications-of-open-cannibalism)), but I've just restarted New Vegas with the intent of playing a character who never kills humans. I'm told it's possible to win the game this way, though it will be very challenging. (Perhaps moreso since this is the character for whom I chose hardcore mode.)

Is there a way to solve Primm's problems with convicts (and specifically, both get and solve [My Kind of Town](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/My_Kind_of_Town)) without killing any humans?

Comment: That sounds like an awesome goal

Comment: @Rapida: And it's already epic failed. I've sold out and decided that Jackals and Fiends don't count as people. Won't go hunting them, but if I run across them, I'm not going to just turn into mincemeat either. :(

Comment: That's respectable. They're far devoid from humanity anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be? The only spot where you may need to do any fighting at all is getting Beagle out of the hostage situation. But you can lockpick the door in the lobby and find a key on there that lets you sneak past all the convicts.
Getting Mayers as a sheriff is dead easy - you just need some Powder Ganger outfit (you can try to steal one at the powder ganger outpost just south of Goodsprings). Otherwise you can pass Science check to repair Slim Primm or Convince Knight at Mojave outpost to send reinforcements. None of those options involve any fighting at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sneak in Bison Steve Hotel to free deputy Beagle because you need to get the quest from him for a new sheriff in town. Once you got this you can just reprogram Primm Slim (robot) to be the sheriff. Now it's a challenge to get to Beagle without a fight since the moment you enter the hotel, 2-3 thugs come running at you for the kill.